# Likelihood Ratio Test for a Normal distribution with unknown $\mu$ and $\sigma^2=1$

Tags: statistics

> Let $Y_1,...,Y_n$ be a random sample from a Normal distribution with
>   unknown mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2=1$. Consider $H_0:\mu=\mu_0$ against $H_a:\mu\ne\mu_0$. Find the likelihood ratio test, $\lambda$,
>   and its rejection region.

I found that $$\lambda=\exp\left[-\frac{n\left(\bar{y}-\mu_0\right)^2}{2}\right].$$ Then,

$$-2\ln\lambda=n\left(\bar{y}-\mu_0\right)^2.$$

Can I use a theorem to say that $-2\ln\lambda$ has a chi-square distribution with $1$ degree of freedom? I know this is true for the case where the variance, $\sigma^2$, is simply known, but is it the same for the case where the variance equals a specific number, such as $1$?

Comment: How did you get $\overline y$ inside parentheses?

Comment: @NCh $\sum(y_i-\mu_0)^2=\sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2+n(\bar{y}-\mu_0)^2$, so the first term cancels with the one from the denominator in $L(\mu_0)/L(\bar{y})$

Comment: Where is $\mu$ in your LR?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I plugged $\mu_0$ into the likelihood of the random sample, so $\mu$ got replaced with $\mu_0$.

Comment: Oh I see you plugged in $\bar y $ in for the other one presumably since that's the maximum likelihood value. The hypothesis test asks you to compare $\mu$ and $\mu_0$ though where neither of them are necessarily equal to $\bar y.$

Comment: @sucksatmath O'k. Under $H_0$ the random variable $\overline y$ has normal distribution with mean $\mu_0$ and variance $1/n$, so $\sqrt{n}(\overline y-\mu_0)$ has standard normal distribution and then its square has chi-square distribution with $1$ degree of freedom.

Comment: @NCh Then, would the rejection region be $|Z|>z_{\alpha/2}$ where $Z=\sqrt n (\bar{y}-\mu_0)$?

Comment: Sure. Or, equivalent, $Z^2 > h_{\alpha}$, where $P(\chi^2_1>h_{\alpha})=\alpha$.